# Windows 10 PPTP Client Does Not Work

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn, remote

I am running Windows 10 Home and attempting to use the built-in PPTP client to access a remote VPN server. As a test, I attempted the same using Linux Mint's built-in VPN client, and everything works fine - so the issue does not have to do with either site's routers or firewalls.

With Linux, I am able to connect and ping hosts on the remote subnet. With Windows 10, however, I am experiencing some bizarre problems:

1) I am able to "establish" a PPTP VPN connection only if I have enabled IPv6 on the VPN adapter. In this case, the VPN connects (verifiable on the VPN server logs), but I have no access to the remote network whatsoever. I can't even ping the remote gateway. Here are the results of ipconfig after attempting the connection with IPv6 enabled:

[image: 2)].

If I disable IPv6, the connection will not work at all. Any VPN connection attempt fails. Very peculiar, because the remote network does not use IPv6...IPv4 only

[image]

Here are more details:

Local subnet - 192.168.0.0/24

Remote subnet - 192.168.1.0/24

I have tried to fix the problem with the following methods:

a) Uninstalled/reinstalled WAN Miniport adapters for IPv4, IPv6, and PPTP

b) Require MS-CHAPv2 encryption on VPN adapter

c) Toggled "Use remote default gateway"

d) Added routes to the Windows 10 client for the remote subnet. Not sure if I did this correctly as I am unfamiliar with the syntax. I tried:

> route add 192.168.1.0 [remote network] mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 [local gateway]

I simply cannot get this to work. Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

P.S. I can't use anything other than PPTP, unfortunately... Not my choice.